# how to use query results in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to use results variable from `mysql` in `node.js` app.
I want to use results variable inside `connection.query` function.
Can anyone help me?

```
connection.query(sql, function (error, results) {
    if (error) throw error;
});
```

EDIT: Sorry, I just want to use it (results inside that connection.query function) outside that function. 
I have code like this:

```
var sql= "SELECT count(*) AS hitung FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'table' ";
connection.query(sql, function (error, results) { 
    if (error) throw error; 
});
```

I want to use that results in another function like:

```
function example() {
    for (i=0; i<results; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    };
};
```

Comment: What you want to achieve? What you are looking for? Please clear your question.

Comment: You can use it. Whats the problem??

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far

Comment: **want to use results variable inside connection.query fn**: Its there already. Try to log it `console.log(results)` & you might have a better idea how do you want to use it and ask with an explanation.

Comment: I edited the question, sorry. I just confused to explain my problem

Answer (score 0):

you can create a async function and get result through sql then you can use it outside of function.

```
async function getData () {
    try {
         var sql= "SELECT count(*) AS hitung FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'table' ";
         let result = await connection.query(sql); 
         result.map(val => {
             console.log(val);
         });
    }
    catch(exception) {
         console.log(exception)
    }
}
```

OR

```
    async function getData () {
        try {
             var sql= "SELECT count(*) AS hitung FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'table' ";
             let result = await connection.query(sql); 
             return result;
        }
        catch(exception) {
             console.log(exception)
        }
    }
    async function example() {
         let result = await this.getData();
         result.map(val => {
             console.log(val);
         }
   }
```

Comment: The results I mean is the variable inside connection.query(sql, function (error, results). I want to use it in another function.